selenium control chrome default behavior： handle protocols
My web automation codes using selenium encounters the xdg-open popup problem, which I cannot close with selenium api. After 2 days search and test, I found 2 solutions:
solution 1. start chrome webdriver with prefs like below, in chrome-129.0:
prefs = {'protocol_handler.policy.auto_launch_protocols_from_origins':[
    {
        'protocol': 'protocol-name',
        'allowed_origins':['https://domain-allowed-calling-this-protocol/']
    }
]}
ops.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

(by the way, there is no web+ before the custom protocol name as some site mentioned.)
This will prevent the popup with checkbox for the custom protocol, but automatically open a new empty chrome window which is left open after my code call webdriver.quit().
solution 2. like the image below (also in chrome-129.0), I tried to set the default behavior to Don't allow sites to handle protocols:

I found this config in chrome gui resulted in chrome's Preferences file:
"custom_handlers":{"enabled":false,"ignored_protocol_handlers":[],"registered_protocol_handlers":[]}

But this config does not work, neither on gui or through selenium.
And there is no deny option on the xdg-open popup, only 'always allow'. This Chrome feature on linux is really anoying.
Is there a way to turn off xdg on linux?
or How does this protocol handler feature works in Chrome?
or Is there some other way to solve this xdg-open popup problem?

final solution:
In docker container (images: selenium/standalone-chrome:129.0-chromedriver-129.0), under /etc/opt/ directory (initally empty), create chrome/policies/managed/ sub directory, then create file blocklist.json with content:
{ "URLBlocklist": ["third-party-protocol-name-1://*", "third-party-protocol-name-2://*"] }

Then restart chrome, the xdg-open popup stop popping.
